# Add files to folders

Tags: batch-file

I have fildes witht he names:

fd3_xxx
fd3_xx1
fd3_xx2
fd6_xxx
fd6_xx1
fd6_xx2

How can I write a batch file that would put all the "fd3" files in a folder called "fd3", and all the "fd6" files into a folder called "fd6'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   for /F "delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      if not exist "%%b" md "%%b"
      move "%%a" "%%b"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
xcopy fd3_* fd3 /i
xcopy fd6_* fd6 /i
del fd3_* /f /q
del fd6_* /f /q
```

Maybe try it on some test folders first to make sure it does what you want it to.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have to create the folder on the fly. For example, if there is a file called fd5_xxx1. I will have to automatically create this folder and move this file into it.

Comment: The first x number of characters will always follow an Underscore. For example, it could be BBBB_ or GGGGGG_